# Direction of wood flooring

Tags: floor

Flooring will run long ways parallel to walls in hallway. Then the hallway runs into the living room with a large white brick fireplace at the far end. How should the wood be laid? There is a bank of 3 large windows on the left side of this room, not on the wall with the fireplace. The living room then l's into the dining room.

Answer (score 1):

USUALLY, for the sake of aesthetics, wood flooring is laid parallel to the longest wall(s). There are times, though, when - because of the floor joist direction and lack of rigidity in the subfloor - the other (perpendicular to the longest walls) direction is better.

If the flooring is laid crosswise to the floor joists, it's easier to get the mopboards/baseboards scribed or flexed to match it - there's less ripple.

Answer (score 0):

True hardwood flooring is run perpendicular to the members of the substructure (floor joists) to add strength and minimize sagging (for engineered flooring this is less important). If that schema runs contrary to a hallway its not uncommon to have a correctional threshold at the ends of the hallway to ensure the flooring is running "down" the length.

To be perfectly up front, if you're talking about real hardwood its probably best to bring in a professional crew. No offense, but it takes no small amount of skill to get a hardwood floor "right" (not to mention the many, many industry specific tools) and most diyers will make a mess of it on their first try. Sometimes it pays to bring in the pro's. If you're talking engineered flooring it's definitely more approachable (mostly because it's pre-finished) but you still have to plan it out very carefully (see link below):

http://hardwoodfloorsmag.com/articles/article.aspx?articleid=203&zoneid=2